# UnityContainer.cs not found

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

[image: This shows me when i try to instantiate UnityContainer]

```
IUnityContainer ioc = new UnityContainer();
```

When i'm in debug mode that picture pop up... My program is just simple console application for inversion of control practice.

Comment: were you pressing f11 on that line?

Comment: when i press f11 same window pops up but with StagedStrategyChain.cs not found

Comment: you can't debug the code without having the source / pdb file, just press f10 on that line..

Comment: But when I compile the program I got exception because of it

Answer (score 0):

I got badly configured my container. Problem solved